# how can I remove the top border on UIToolBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have set my UIToolBar tint color to some value, and there is this border line that I see in which I want to remove:

[image]

How do I remove this black border>

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Correct answer is the one by totalitarian...FYI. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14448645/627299

My response is still below for reference.

---

Here's what I did with my WHITE background toolbar...

```
whiteToolBar.layer.borderWidth = 1;
whiteToolBar.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
```

Perhaps you could do the same thing with your color instead.

Comment: It's much cleaner to use whiteToolBar.clipToBounds = YES

Comment: Swift for @jomafer's comment: `myToolbar.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: I hereby join the club of people thanking their past self

Comment: Set Clips To Bounds in either Interface Builder or as mentioned above, it's. a better solution.

Comment: `clipToBounds` is not ideal since iPhone X because it will leave the safe area blank

Answer (score 145):

You can do like this:

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: That didn't help me in iOS 6

Comment: This works for a bare UIToolbar as well; doesn't have to be part of a navigation controller.

Comment: Works like a charm on iOS 7.x with SDK 7.

Comment: *Nico*, this is working because "clipsToBounds" makes a view draw only within it's bounds. in this case, a layer's border draws outside of the view's bounds, so settings "clipsToBounds" to true "disable" it's border.

Comment: `clipsToBounds = YES` breaks a toolbar's look on the iPhone X. It hides the top border, but it also stops the toolbar's background from extending to the bottom edge of the screen.

Comment: In my case, I am just using the toolbar as the `inputAccessoryView` for a text field (displayed above the keyboard), so the bottom safe area is no issue.

Answer (score 50):

```
toolbar1.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Worked for me incase someone is still trying with Navigational bar

Comment: This causes the bottom to be cut off at the safe area boundary on iPhone X

Answer (score 17):

setShadowImage to [UIImage new]

Comment: Without a doubt, the proper answer

Comment: This is the one you need to use to avoid losing toolbar color in safe areas such as at bottom of iPhone X i.e. [self setShadowImage:UIImage.new forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny];

Answer (score 12):

```
navigationController?.toolbar.barTintColor = .white

navigationController?.toolbar.setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .any)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Setting the style to UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent did it for me (iOS 6)

Answer (score 3):

create a 1 pixel x 1 pixel clear image and call it clearPixel.png

```
toolbar.setShadowImage(UIImage(named: "clearPixel.png"), forToolbarPosition: UIBarPosition.any)
```

Comment: Can also simply do `UIImage()`, no need for an asset

Answer (score 2):

this doesn't work consistently on iOS versions, doesn't seem to work on iOS7. i answered this in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19893602/452082 and you can modify that solution to just remove the background shadow (and leave your `toolbar.backgroundColor` whatever color you like)

Answer (score 2):

The `clipsToBounds` technique clips the UIToolBar's shadow as well as the background view. On an iPhone X, that means the background no longer reaches outside the [safe area](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area).

[image: Incorrect UIToolBar on iPhone X]

The solution below uses a mask to clip only the top of the UITabBar. The mask is rendered in a UIToolBar subclass, and the mask frame is kept updated in an override of `layoutSubviews`.

```swift
class Toolbar: UIToolbar {

    fileprivate let maskLayer: CALayer = {
        let layer = CALayer()
        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        return layer
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }

    fileprivate func initialize() {
        layer.mask = maskLayer
        // Customize toolbar here
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        // height is an arbitrary number larger than the distance from the top of the UIToolbar to the bottom of the screen
        maskLayer.frame = CGRect(x: -10, y: 0, width: frame.width + 20, height: 500)
    }

}
```

[image: Correct UIToolBar on iPhone X]

Comment: This works for me on any device BUT the iPhone X.  I copied the code line-for-line, creating a new Swift class and specifying the class in Interface Builder.

Comment: @E-Madd Perhaps the Interface Builder is the difference. In our setup, we are programmatically creating the UINavigationController with a UINavigationBar and UIToolbar subclass, like so: `let navigationController = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: NavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: Toolbar.self)`

Comment: I refactored to this with no change.  I still have the border.  Actually, it seems to be a gap between the main view and the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

I got a bit confused with these answers but I was missing the point that you were using an Outlet so just to be clear here is the swift code I used to hide the border:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var ToolBar: UIToolbar!

    //MARK View Functions
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // Hide the bottom toolbar's top border
        ToolBar.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

I had dragged a toolbar to the bottom of a view for this and it's not the top nav bar some other questions refer to.

Comment: Great, this worked. Could you explain why, though? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

````
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionBottom barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UIToolbar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionBottom];

[UIToolbar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor ...];```
````